# Updating custom program over 4G

Tags: networking, software-installation, update, software-development

I have been working on a project that uses a Raspberry Pi 3b+ to send collected data to my server. This Raspberry Pi is setup with a 4G module and is able to send and receive data to and from my server. Now I want to be able to do occasional updates over 4G, since I want to place the Raspberry somewhere I cannot access it that easily. I am not sure what the best approach is to make this reliable and not massively consume data.

For the program I wrote:

- I wrote a web server so that the server can access the pi and make requests (such as auto update).
- I wrote a data collector that collects data and stores it on the pi (**I want this particular program to be updateable remotely**), this is also written in nodejs

I have thought of maybe using git, since this only tracks changed files? Or else compile it and make it available for download?

I would love to hear some suggestions or better approaches, because at this point I am not sure what is best to d.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to remotely manage (and update) RPi is like with any other Linux: via SSH. Connect to it with SSH client and do anything you want to, including `apt update` / `apt dist-upgrade`.

There could be problem to connect to something remotely via 4G, because for that you need it to have a public routable address or at least some port forwarded to it, and network operators unwilling to provide that or request some additional money. This could be solved this way: on your server configure a VPN server (OpenVPN will do), configure RPi to connect to this server at startup and maintain a connection (reconnect if disconnected, etc.). It wouldn't consume much resources. Then you will be able to connect to it via this VPN channel.